# Aiogram. Как проверить отсутствие состояния?

Tags: python, aiogram

У меня есть набор состояний для всех пользователей.
Они отвечают за меню, за другие панели.
Я могу спокойно проверять состояния, типо если у тебя состояние **МЕНЮ**, то ты можешь нажимать на кнопки какие-то из меню.
Но проблема в том, что при старте ни у одного из пользователей нет состояния.

```
class UserStates(StatesGroup):
    MENU = State()
    RENT = State()
    MY_SHOP = State()
```

***Подскажите как проверять отсутствие состояния или как при старте сделать основным состоянием МЕНЮ.***

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(CommandStart(), state=["*", UserStates.MENU])
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    state = dp.current_state(user=user.id)
    await state.set_state(UserStates.MENU)

    ...
```

Comment: Это срабатывает когда отправляется первое сообщение. В итоге после запуска бот все равно не отвечает на первое сообщение. Может есть способ проверять отсутствие состояния у какой-то группы состояний?

Comment: Обновил ответ, была ошибка